# Syntax of calling a function call inside a component instance

Tags: javascript, react-native, arrow-functions

I have two different components: `MyComponent` and `BookDisplay`

`MyComponent`

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      book: "A"
    }
  }
  updateBook() {
    this.setState({book: "B"})
  }
  render() {
    const {book} = this.state
    return (
      <BookDisplay updateBook = {() => this.updateBook()} book={book} />
    )
  }
}
```

`BookDisplay`

```
const BookDisplay = ({book, updateBook}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text onPress = {updateBook} >
        {book}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

What I'm currently stuck on after going through various JS, react, and react-native resources is trying to understand the one line calling updateBook on the `BookDisplay` component

```
<BookDisplay updateBook={() => this.updateBook()} ... />
```

Is this written in this manner because updateBook is a function defined in `MyComponent` and this is how we assign a prop a function? Why is it not `updateBook={this.updateBook()}` instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question: Is there a reason why you're using classes instead of the newer way of using hooks?

Comment: This is a textbook example out of React Native in Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are passing a function to the updateBook prop:
`<BookDisplay updateBook={() => this.updateBook()} ... />`

But here you are executing the function and passing the result of that function:
`<BookDisplay updateBook={ this.updateBook()} ... />`

The arrow function also binds the `this` object to `MyComponent`.

Inside the `BookDisplay` in some point will try to execute his `updateBook` prop and it is going to be your function

Comment: Thank you. It just clicked and I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

looking at your code "updateBook" function should be called when onPress is called
if you do like updateBook={this.updateBook()}, the function is already executed and return value (if any) is returned/assigned to the updateBook Props, when BookDisplay component is initialised inside the MyComponent.

You can also use like
<BookDisplay updateBook={this.updateBook.bind(this)} ... />

Comment: in the last part you will need to bind the function o this `<BookDisplay updateBook={this.updateBook.bind(this)} ... />`